# Missing address in OSM file

Tags: openstreetmap, latitude-longitude, address, mysql-spatial, osmfilter

I downloaded a part of germany .osm file from geofabrik and extracted all ways and nodes whose tag contains addr-key using [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter):

`osmfilter.exe hessen-latest.osm --keep=addr:*=* --drop-relations --drop-version --drop-author --drop-tags="fixme= source=" > he_nodes_ways.osm`

Then I have written a java console programm which parses the large xml file (using SAXParser) and inserts every single node and way into a mysql data base.

But I've realized that a lot of streets for my own town are missing in the mysql database, even I've collected all addresses from nodes and ways. As soon I now, relations doesn't have address information. The missing addresses in my database exist in open street map.

Does anyone have further information or knows another way how to import osm address information with geo informations into a mysql database.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [osm2pgsql](https://osm2pgsql.org/). This is a robust program to convert OSM data to PostgreSQL, but **not** MySQL directly. However, after your data is in PostgreSQL, you can export it again and load it into your MySQL database.

You could also try the [OSM](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html) driver and the [MySQL](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mysql.html#vector-mysql) driver from [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org) to load your data into MySQL. Your would need the [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) CLI tool for this operation.

Comment: Thank's for your reply! I will try it with osm2pgsql first.